# Why default value is not getting set in tkinter radiobutton?

Tags: python, tkinter, radio-button

I have the code shown below that will iterate through the list of names in a dictionary and then create radio buttons. Prior the iteration, have set/initialized the default value. The almost same code is set in a different way and the default values is not getting set, and not sure what am I missing. Any assistance will be appreciated.

Working code

[image]

```
from tkinter import *

root = Tk()
root.title('Trevieew API App')
methods = [
             ('Monday', 1),
             ('Tuesday', 2),
             ('Wednesday', 3),
             ('Thursday', 4),
             ('Friday', 5)
    ]
_row = 0
v = IntVar()
v.set(1)
for method, value in methods:
    b = Radiobutton(root, text=method, variable=v, value=value)
    _row += 1
    b.grid(row=_row, column=0, sticky=W)

root.mainloop()
```

NOT working copy

[image]

```
from tkinter import *


class App:

    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        master.title('App Tool')
        self.radiobuttons()

    def radiobuttons(self):
        _row = 0
        methods = [
                 ('Monday', 1),
                 ('Tuesday', 2),
                 ('Wednesday', 3),
                 ('Thursday', 4),
                 ('Friday', 5)
             ]
        v = IntVar()
        v.set(1)
        for method, value in methods:
            b = Radiobutton(root, text=method, variable=v, value=value)
            _row += 1
            b.grid(row=_row, column=0, sticky=W)


root = Tk()
my_gui = App(root)
root.mainloop()
```

Comment: I really appreciate your comment, you were right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Problem can be because `v` in class is local variable which is destroyed when it ends method `radiobuttons`. Use `self.` to keep it.

```
    self.v = IntVar()
    self.v.set(1)

    for method, value in methods:
        b = Radiobutton(root, text=method, variable=self.v, value=value)
        _row += 1
        b.grid(row=_row, column=0, sticky=W)
```

Comment: This solve the problem. I believe was mistakenly been advise from pycharm that the variable was outside of def __ini__.